# Need to run a mobile robot on batteries

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated, mobile-robot

I made a 4wd mobile robot with an 4 DoF robotic arm on it and currently in process of designing a power board for my robot. I would like get a **detailed road map** on designing a power board for the robot. Here is a brief overview of my hardware:

- The robot has **8 joints** which each of the motor runs with 12V (stall current: 800mA, nominal run: ~200mA),
- The control board works with 5V (nominal current draw: 500mA, max: 1.5A),
- Overall(averge) energy consumption of the robot is around **6 Watts** (max 18Watts).

Here is what I have done so far for powering the robot:

- I am using 2 ncr18650b battery in series with a cheap of-the-shelf battery management system (BMS), so I do not kill the batteries while over-running the robot,
- Nominal voltages of these two batteries are 7.2V where I use one boost converter for driving the motors with 12V and a buck converter for driving the controller board with 5V,
- I have to unplug the batteries when ever I need to charge them (since I do not have a charging circuit for the batteries yet).

Since I was working with the rest of the robot, I just built this battery setup in two days and it was working and enough. Now I would like to focus on developing a professional power management module. Here is simply what I need (need to understand) for designing the power circuit board:

- I would like to power the robot with 2 18650 batteries in series,
- the batteries (in series) should be charged without unplugging (from a 12V DC input port),
- the robot can also be powered on while charging the batteries,
- I would also like to monitor the batteries,
- I would both want to supply 5V for controller board and 12V for the motors from the same battery unit. I encounted a problem with my cheap dump setup which; if motors draw much current from boost converter (12V), buck converters 5V drops. So, I would also like to prevent this happening.

As I am going to through the ICs and datasheet, I assume I need:

- a 2S battery charging IC with a **power path management** (eg: [bq24075](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24075-q1.pdf)) to also power the robot while charging the batteries,
- a 2S battery management IC for balancing/protecting/monitoring the batteries (which are in series),
- a boost converter for 12V,
- a buck converter for 5V,

I am fairly experience with designing circuits but never worked on a power management circuit for batteries. I will appreciate if you give me detailed road map or resources for reading (schematics/articles etc.).

**EDIT**

A conceptual block diagram
[image]

Comment: stall current: 0,8mA, ?? 0.8A

Comment: You are on the right path. You need to make a conceptual block diagram and post it for review. Check out Linear Tech, they make all the parts you would need.

Comment: stall current: 0.8A. Edited. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. I will post, as soon as I draw the diagram.

Comment: The block diagram is a good start but needs more detail. For example what is Battery Monitoring interface, I2C? You have 12V going into a battery charging block but I do not see it can be used power the system while charging the batteries. Power Path is just shown as wires, there must be more to it.

Comment: I made an update. Tried to be more clear but not sure how to show more details on a block diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Efficiency, Features for Active or Passive Balance, cost, complexity, time budget,  spare parts , temperature rise, thermal design of each block in addition with electrical design with max load while charging and operating.  ( which could be almost twice the 1C current rate or ~ 6.7A  !!  and that BMS chip is limited to 1.5A)

### So ALWAYS start with Specs before you waste too much time.

Battery background https://www.digikey.com/en/ptm/t/texas-instruments/introduction-to-battery-management-part-1/tutorial

If starting power at full voltage is  0.8A*12V = 9.6W per motor.

What software restrictions limit 5 motor starts at full acceleration?

I suggest you have PWM control V/f of motor slew rate controlled to limit current which will also improve stability.

Assuming you have done this and peak power is 18W with 2 cells at 3350 mAh typ each @ 3.6V =  12Wh * 2 = 24 Wh max then your max load will be slighly more than a 24/18 = 1.33C load rate. Which seems reasonable for experimentation at max load.

Batteries will be very well balanced (<<1%) when fresh and degrade very slightly then exponentially before EOL (end of life)   Meaning that charge balance by cell monitoring is necessary for internal charging.

Try to keep between 20% and 90% State of Charge by useage. 90% is shortly after going from CC mode to CV mode.  But if you have a good BMS chip, follow their advice. I only suggest smaller DOD range to extend battery total Wh*charge cycle life span. Using 50% will double battery life capacity.

Using a good Full MOSFET bridge with a good BMS and good software for slew rate control helps on the servo side while braking also recycles charge to battery.  It depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your precious comment.

 - Today I have not answer for efficieny, balances and temperature,
 - Since I am under a research budget, so I do not have a restriction for budget and complexity,
 - I have all the time until I create a working prototype,
 - Nothing limits the motor currents for now (the robot may hit a wall so all wheels may stall, the arm may try to lift a heavy object so all the joints mamy stall),
 - I am controlling each motor with PWM and monitoring each motors current draw.

Comment: Is this a Stepper or Servo feedback design?   WIth gears or?

Comment: Geared dc motors driven by DRV8801's. PWM frequency  ~21.9kHz.